# Summation required from 1 to infinity by changing the limits.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

[image]

[image]

I'm  not able to understand how they've obtained the expression in the secnd part by starting the summation from 1. I can get (0.05*1.09*1.07)/(1.05^2) multiplied by the sum from 3 to infinity of (1.05/1.04)^t but from that point onward I don't understand how to simplify the expression so my summation is from 1 to infinity rather than from 3 to infinity.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.

Write out the first few terms of both versions of the series.

What do you see when you compare them?